# Small signal model of circuit with Darlington pair and source follower

Tags: circuit-analysis, small-signal

I have some issues with drawing the small signal model of the circuit (picture 1.) I get confused when there are multiple transistors, especially when they are linked together like the Darlington pair.

This is the attempt I have made so far.

Could someone tell me if the redrawn circuit is correct?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there some reason you like drawing polarities inverted with positive ground ?  This is not a standard logic diagram as inverted even if functionally correct.

Comment: Hmm, do you mean in the first picture? If so, that is a circuit from the assignment, I have not drawn it, my examinator has. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: tell your examiner he is using inverted logic diagrams

Comment: Yes sir I will.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 - I disagree. Schematics where PNP transistors dominate are usually shown with positive ground and the negative supply drawn at the top of the schematic.

Comment: perhaps often done,  but for a Logic Diagram that's inverted logic. @KevinWhite I've worked with many giant corporations, far east and west and never once observed that , even with ECL using a 0V and -V

Comment: @david31 I'd be very judicious about _telling_ someone in a position of power over you that they're wrong.  _Asking_ why they did it that way may be informative.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I don't think it's common now, but in the days of PNP germanium transistors, radio schematics would show the negative rail on top and a positive ground more often than not.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 - This isn't logic. It is a linear amplifier. ECL schematics that I've used had positive at the top. As TimWescott says this was common when PNP transistors dominated. It is rare to see it nowadays and a p-type JFET is virtually non-existent. Wow, it looks like Solitron makes them

Comment: @KevinWhite  Schematic Diagrams are called Logic Diagrams because the y follow a standard set of logical rules like ideal LRC,  and 0 impedance traces while ground everywhere=0V with positive up and reading generally left to right. It as nothing to do with Logic components which of course have analog parameters.  Think of it as a graphical logical symbolic language. Can you name any corporation that does what you suggest?